# freeware extJs designer

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I want to build a web site (private POC and later maybe commercial).

It will include file-browser layout.

Is there any freewarw UI designer anyone can recommend for my goal?

I liked ExtJs, but it's only 30 days trail

and later it forces my application to be open-source, right?

http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-designer-preview

Can I use the designer and then make custom changes and thus make my application not open source?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a free UI designer for extJS. If you purchase a commercial license for ExtDesigner, your application is not required to comply with GPL licensing:

> Ext Designer outputs code for your project through the Sencha Ext JS
>   framework. If you are developing commercial applications with Ext
>   Designer, you need to purchase an Ext JS commercial license. Without
>   an Ext JS commercial license, the output of your Ext Designer project
>   must comply with the GPL version 3 open source license.

**Additional Information:**

Purchasing a commercial license is not a sin.

See http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/license/

Comment: any other free UI designer for windows like theme?

Comment: not nescessarly, any Ui designer that will help me build web file-browser.

Comment: It'd difficult to tell what you're asking. The only other suggestion I can make is to check out Visual Web Developer Express -  http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about how compatible this is with the latest ExtJS version but it feels pretty good. http://www.projectspace.nl/

Regards!